# Algoritmo no VisualG sobre números primos em uma estrutura de repetição

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Sou novo na área de programação e preciso de uma ajuda em um exercício da faculdade, eu preciso de um algoritmo no VisualG que mostre os números primos entre um número n1 e um número n2, usando uma estrutura de repetição, onde n1 e n2 são informados pelo usuário. O algoritmo que eu fiz é esse (mas não sei o que falta para funcionar):

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
c, i, n1, n2, p: inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
escreva ("Digite um número incial: ")
leia(n1)
escreva ("Digite um número final: ")
leia (n2)
para c de n1 ate n2 faca
     p<-0
     para i de n1 ate c faca
          se(cmod i=0) entao
                  p<-p+1
          fimse
     fimpara
     se (p=2) entao
        escreva (c)
     fimse
fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem sentido você fazer:

```
para c de n1 ate n2 faca
     ...
     para i de n1 ate c faca
```

Outra coisa é que `cmod` é o nome de uma variável e `c mod`você está utilizando o operador resto da divisão.

Tente:

```
Var
    c, i, n1, n2, p: inteiro
Inicio
    escreva ("Digite um número inicial: ")
    leia(n1)
    escreva ("Digite um número final: ")
    leia (n2)
    para c de n1 ate n2 faca
          p<-0
          para i de 1 ate c faca
               se(c mod i = 0) entao
                       p<-p+1
               fimse
          fimpara
          se (p=2) entao
             escreva (c)
          fimse
    fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou, era isso que eu precisava, não estava conseguindo achar o erro, só alterei um pouco colocando alguns espaços para ajudar na exibição e no entendimento quando o algoritmo ser executado. Valeu pela ajuda